# How to Remove Email Auto Fill in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

The auto fill feature for Mozilla's Thunderbird email client makes a lot of troubles to me.I cannot type the right email adress as when I type two chaptions Thunderbird sugguest me a wrong one. Strangely enough, I have already cancel the adress auto-complete feature in my client. Is there anyone could help me please?

Comment: Check if the address is not in your contacts / address book.

Comment: As pabouk said, just go into your address book and remove the entries. It will then prevent the autofill to match email address.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot of posts and not working on My Max OS Sierra This is what I had to do
went to contact in my apple computer highlighted all tge current contacts I wanted to see. Then exported to desk top ( now I have something to bring back in with out the names I didn't want to auto drop)
Thunderbird 
go to address book
delete all addresses in all files 
Click on all addresses 
go to Tools on top
Click on Import
go to where you exported the vcf files I did it on desktop
Import
Click Finished
Transfer the names by highlighting all iof them and drag and drop to Personal address Book
All files should be clear except for personal address book
Delete the empty folders you wont need them
\Now you have a fresh contacts list 
The problem I had that the auto drop 1st choice wasn't the one I wanted to the one I wanted had to come first by changing the other names alphabet from the ones I want.
I hope you can understand my ex plantation It doesn't take as long as it seems

Comment: This is very hard to follow because it is a wall of text with no punctuation or formatting, and random capitalization.  Can you make it readable?